# Wrong roman numbering in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I have two types on numbering, roman for toc tof and tables and arabic for the document.

I'm using

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

and the code is written this way.

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\phantom{a}\mbox{}\clearpage

\listoffigures
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}


\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\phantom{a}\mbox{}\clearpage

\listoftables
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\phantom{a}\mbox{}\clearpage
```

[image]

As you can see in the index they are not correctly numbered. The numbers on toc correspond to the last page of each section.

Comment: Did you compile at least twice?

Comment: @Werner yes. :/

Comment: Can this be replicated with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your current settings, the `\addcontentsline` commands are too late in the code (once the lists have been typeset). The correct order should be something like

```
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

And similarly for the other lists.

Also, remove these lines:

```
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    \clearpage      
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
    \listoftables 

    \clearpage      
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect LIST OF FIGURES}
    \listoffigures
```

This will solve your problem. Just put `\protect`.